# How to use a list as a class variable so that instance object (arguments) are appended to the list?

Tags: python, list, class-variables

I would like to simply make a list of kinds of coffe, but get an error stating that the list is not defined. Do I have to use `self` in the constructor when referencing to a classvariable?

I have tried changing the `return` statement to return `self.coffelist.append(name)`, but then get another error: `'Function' object has no attribute 'append'`.

```
class coffe:

    coffelist = []

    def __init__(self,name,origin,price):
        self.name = name
        self.origin = origin
        self.price = price
        return (self.coffelist.append(self.name))

    def coffelist(self):
        print(coffelist)


c1=coffe("blackcoffe","tanz",55)
c2=coffe("fineroasted","ken",60)
```

Comment: `coffelist` is a `class coffe` _method_, not a `list`, and function objects don't have a method named `append()`. You need to rename your `coffeelist()` method and add a `self.coffelist = []` to the `__init__()` method.

Comment: What's a "coffesort"?

Comment: yes naming the function that way was another misstake. great! But if I define the list under init, the list is just locally (added by reference to that object). I wanted every new class object's name added to the list though.  just different sorts of coffe.

Comment: Declaring `coffelist = []` at the class level will make it be shared by all instances of the `coffe` class (so you wouldn't want to create it in the `__init__()` method). Note that the `__init__()` method does not return anything, nor does the `list.append()` method, so the way you're using or trying to with both of those is wrong—although appending the `name` to the class attribute `list` is fine. You can reference the current value of the shared class attribute using `coffe.coffelist`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you named one of your methods as `coffelist`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this shows how to do what you want. I also modified your code to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and corrected some misspelled words.

```py
class Coffee:  # Class names should Capitalized.

    coffeelist = []  # Class attribute to track instance names.

    def __init__(self,name,origin,price):
        self.name = name
        self.origin = origin
        self.price = price
        self.coffeelist.append(self.name)

    def print_coffeelist(self):
        print(self.coffeelist)


c1 = Coffee("blackcoffee", "tanz", 55)
c1.print_coffeelist()  # -> ['blackcoffee']
c2 = Coffee("fineroasted", "ken", 60)
c1.print_coffeelist()  # -> ['blackcoffee', 'fineroasted']

# Can also access attribute directly through the class:
print(Coffee.coffeelist)  # -> ['blackcoffee', 'fineroasted']
```

Answer (score 0):

yes thanks that's  exactly what I wanted! 
I wasnt sure.. I thought you could do 2 things simultaneously in the return statement, both return append. I guess allot of times python is very flexible and sometimes not. thanks